# Micro-Sd memory problem

Tags: pi-2, kali

i am using a 64gb micro-SD but after using etcher for kali (7 Gb), i have only 55 mb left! 
How can i solve?

I tried to burn the .img again but the problem is everytime the same

Comment: you have `expanded` the filesystem haven't you? It seems latest `raspbian stretch` does this "automatically" on first boot, though I've had one failure and had to do it "manually" using raspi-config - of course, you're not using raspbian, so, you'll probably need to do this manually yourself

Comment: 55MB is probably the rest of the boot partition. Please add info about partitioning and how you burn the .img!!! As it is now, a lot of needed info is missing!